# Understanding javascript closure

Tags: javascript

```
function makeHelpCallback(help) {
  return function() {
    showHelp(help);
  };

//array elements here

  for (var i = 0; i < helpText.length; i++) {
    var item = helpText[i];
    document.getElementById(item.id).onfocus = makeHelpCallback(item.help);
}
```

I am having trouble understanding the last line. I have never seen the equal sign used in that way,

Comment: It's like `element.onclick = function() { alert(); }`, it's just an element with an event on one side, and a function call on the other.

Comment: That whole block is invalid... You are missing a `}` somewhere...

Comment: In what way? It is a mere assignment like any other.

Comment: Where is the closing brace `}`? I'm assuming before the "array elements here" comment?

Comment: Regarding why a closure is needed here, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: @insertusernamehere Yes, there is. See the two questions linked from the comments.

Answer (score 6):

> I have never seen the equal sign used in that way

It assigns the return value of a function call (another function in this case; they are first class objects so can be passed around) to a property of an object.

Comment: Thanks everyone and especially Quentin, I think i get it.